# Efficient algorithm to calculate the dihedral angles in a hexahedron?

Tags: loops, data-structures

To calculate the dihedral angles between two planes, one needs four points: two lie on the intersecting edge and two lie on each corresponding plane. The full mathematical formulation can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/315171/269712).

Now my question is concerned with data structure and how to efficiently calculate all the dihedral angles in a hexahedron. Suppose I have a data structure as followed

```
vertices[8] // Contains all the vertices of the hexahedral
edges[12] = {{vertices[i], vertices[k]}, {vertices[i], vertices[j]}...} // Each cell contain an edge formed by the two vertices.
face[6] = { {vertices[i], vertices[j], vertices[k], vertices[l]}, {..} ...} // Each face contains the four vertices that form a face of the hexahedral.
```

Supposed all the faces of this hexahedron is flat (i.e. all four vertices of a face is coplanar), what is a good strategy to calculate all the dihedral angles of a hexahedral being defined in this way?

At the moment, my pseudocode looks like

```
for all edges
  loop through the face list to find all faces that contain the edges
     for the face that both contain the vertices of the sharing edge, find the other points 
      then used the formulation proposed above.
```

which appears quite clumsy and slow. Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1. For each face, find the normal vector.  Take the cross product of the two diagonal vectors and normalize to unit length; then
2. For each pair of adjacent faces with normal vectors A and B, the dihedral angle between them is acos(A \dot B)

Comment: How would you find the adjacent faces, then?

Comment: Easy enough to find the other faces that share an edge, or share 2 vertices... but usually if you _know_ it's a hexahedron then the faces in the faces array will be in a particular order and you will know which ones are adjacent.

Comment: That would leave 4 adjacent faces. How do you then deal with any possible repetition calculation for the same dihedral angle?

Comment: You just wouldn't calculate the same one twice.  If you're finding adjacent faces in a loop, then only find the ones with greater indexes in the faces array.